# ASP.NET MVC: No parameterless constructor defined for this object with Lightinject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, constructor, code-injection, light-inject

I have started using `LightInject`, but getting `No parameterless constructor defined for this object` error. 
The code as below,

Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    var container = new ServiceContainer();
    container.Register<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
    container.RegisterControllers();
    container.EnableMvc();
}
```

Controller:

```
public HomeController(IEmployeeRepository repo)
{
    repository = repo;
}
```

Can anyone help me.

Stack Trace:

> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,
>   Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +232    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +66    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +110
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'TestTools.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure
>   that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +247
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +438
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +226
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +326    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +157
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +301    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Can you resolve your repository as `container.GetInstance<IEmployeeRepository>();`? Has  `EmployeeRepository` a  parameterless constructor?

Comment: Yes, EmployeeRepository has no parameter.

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: its been added now with the main thread

Comment: Can you also add the definition of `EmployeeRepository`, at least the class with the signatures of the constructor(s)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, finally it worked after removing the current package and updated with 'LightInject.Mvc.Source'